# Kibana is rounding off the string value that I'm putting it on MDC

Tags: kibana, log4j2

I've implemented log4j2 in my Spring Boot application. I'm logging the output to the console as Json so that Kibana application can read these logs. Whenever I'm trying to log a value like this - `MDC.put("user_id", "71368935.4457605132")` , it gets logged properly but it appears as `71,368,935.446` on Kibana. How can I make it appear as a string value on Kibana?